# Is it possible to change variables inside a closure in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, closures

Let's suppose I have the following:

```
(function() {
  let myVar = 300;
  window.myFunc = function() {
    console.log(myVar);
  };
})();
```

Without changing the above code, can you think of a way to change the `myVar` variable? I mean from the outside, can you do something like:

```
window.myFunc.__closure__.myVar = 10;
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this? Or are you just curious if it's possible. Without modifying the code the answer is no. Or at least, you shouldn't be able to.

Comment: via Dev-tools; just set a break point in any function that can see this variable. via code, No, not possible, not without changing the code; unless they use `evil()` somewhere where this variable is visible, and you can inject some code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*No, it is not possible because the scope of the variable is the function's block.*

The only way of modifying something inside of the closure is thru properties in the current lexical context (in this case the `window` object).

```js
(function() {
  this.myVar = this.myVar || 300;
  window.myFunc = function() {
    console.log(myVar);
  };
})();

myVar = "Ele";
myFunc();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could define a global function that changes the variable:

```js
(function() {
  let myVar = 300;
  window.myFunc = function() {
    console.log(myVar);
  };
  window.setMyVar = value => {
    myVar = value;
  };
})();

myFunc();
setMyVar(10);
myFunc();
```

Or you could return `setMyVar`:

```js
const setMyVar = (function() {
  let myVar = 300;
  window.myFunc = function() {
    console.log(myVar);
  };
  return value => {
    myVar = value;
  };
})();

myFunc();
setMyVar(100);
myFunc();
```

Comment: @Ele Yeah I should have taken a little more time to read the question before answering.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of using a closure is to make variable accessible only to a specific scope. If you then want to change it outside of this scope, why not use a class?

eg.

```
class myClass {
  constructor(var) { this._var = var }
  set var(arg) { this._var = arg }

  yourFunc() { console.log(this._var) }
}
```